# validate CSV (RFC 4180) using JS, (preferably angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, csv

[Question reformulated]

I've got an input type=file that allows the user to choose a file from disk. The actual upload process is already working fine:

upload.html:

```
<input type="file" file-upload accept=".csv" />
```

directive:

```
directive('fileUpload', ['$rootScope',
    function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            scope: true,
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                el.bind('change', function (event) {
                    var file = event.target.files[0];
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('fileSelected', { file: file });
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

controller:

```
$scope.uploadCSVData = {};
$scope.uploadCSVData.name = '';

$scope.submitUpload = function () {
$http({

    url: $api.$options.url + '/upload/list',
    method: 'POST',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
    transformRequest: function (data) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('data', angular.toJson($scope.uploadCSVData));
        formData.append('file' , $scope.file);
        return formData;
    }
```

Now I want to add a method to do some simple validation on the contents of that CSV file. I have read multiple articles about parsing CSV strings and validating them, but they always assume I have the actual string.

In my case, I have a file and - while I can get lots of metadata about the file (such as last edited date, and even filesize) - I do not seem to have access to the data itself within JS so that I can validate it.

```
$scope.$on('fileSelected', function (event, args) {
    $scope.file = args.file;
    console.log($scope.file);
});
```

The object looks like this:

```
File {
    lastModified: 1421877884000
    lastModifiedDate: Wed Jan 21 2015 17:04:44 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
    name: "csv.csv"
    size: 5
    type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

It currently contains one 5-letter string (just to test), but I cannot access the string.

**How can I get the contents of the file into an object that I can then validate with JS?**

Initial tests suggest I can perform an $http GET prior to performing the $http POST - but $http GET wants a URL, which points at a location on the server. I do not have a location on the server, since the user is using an input field to get the file directly. **So how do I point my $http GET at the file that is already stored as $scope.file?**

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution though I cannot guarantee how universally compatible it is. (There seems to be some ambiguity about whether FileReader is supported by all browsers.)

http://caniuse.com/#search=file

```
$scope.$on('fileSelected', function (event, args) {
    $scope.file = args.file;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        $scope.uploadCSVData.valid = $scope.validCSV(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText($scope.file);
});

$scope.validCSV = function(text){
    // regex to test validity of text as CSV
    // returns string if valid, null if invalid
}
```

Comment: Well, I am utterly stumped. As far as I can tell, no one has ever successfully written a CSV validator in JavaScript. So even to though I've got this file in an object, I can't process it. What a waste. Gotta go tell the team that this has to be done server-side.